# How to handle promise response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, async-await, axios

Okay, so I have this situation where I need to make a petition to an endpoint and get the URL of the back-end that i'm actually going to use. I have a file with the configuration of the api where I create the instance with axios.

Before it worked like this, This way I could use the endpoint wherever I needed it:

```
import axios from "axios";

const url =   process.env.API_URL

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: url,
});

export default instance;
```

This is what I'm trying to do now:

```
import axios from "axios";
import qs from "qs";

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const url_endpoint = process.env.URL_ENDPOINT;
const param = urlParams.get("param");

const data = {
  f: "json",
  outFields: "*",
  where: `search_field='${param}'`,
};

const options = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  },
  data: qs.stringify(data),
  url: url_endpoint,
};

const getAPIurl = axios(options).then((res) => {
  console.log(res, "petition1");
  return res.data.features[0].attributes.url_base_pub;
});

const apiURL = async () => {
  const url = await getAPIurl;
  console.log(url, "petition2");
  return url;
};

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: apiURL(),
});

export default instance;
```

When i do `console.log(apiURL())` all I get is a promise, I need to pass the value of the url but I haven't found a way of doing this.

Comment: You need to wait for the result like this `apiURL().then(x => console.log(x))`

Comment: Yeah the thing is that i need to use value of x outside the promise

Comment: So is the issue on your `const instance` code? Is that where you want to capture the resulting URL and use it elsewhere? `instance.baseURL`?

Comment: You only have a value when the promise is no longer pending. Thus, you always need to either `await` or `.then` to get the data - this needs to go all the way up to where the data is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
const value = await apiURL();
```

Then you should have URL as value variable. Since you have defined apiURL() as async function therefore it will always return promise implicitly even if we do not explicitly return promise. you can read about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function